# Adding perimeters around points map layout output QGIS

Tags: qgis, pdf

I'm making a map in QGIS with a number of points in different categories. In the print layout view, it looks like this:

[image]

As one can see, there are black perimeters around the dots, both on the map and in the legend. When I export the map as a pdf, the perimeters suddenly disappear.

[image]

How can I prevent the black perimeters from disappearing in the pdf output of the map?

Comment: What is the type of your point layer (Vector, WMS) ? In the point layer properties, what are the point outline width and unit ? And at which resolution did you exported the map print ?

Comment: @J.Monticolo I'm not sure whether it's a vector or WMS layer. All I can find so far is that it comes from a CSV file. As for the point outline width and unit, I found it's Hairline and the unit is millimeters. The resolution of the export is 300 dpi.

Comment: Ok ! So it's a vector file. Try to fix the outline width to 0.5 millimeters.